# Символьные вычисления в MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Как создать аналитическую запись для данной функции, используя символьные переменные и команды MATLAB:

```
f(x) = {x, 0<=x<=1/2;
       1-x,1/2<=x<=1}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Если доступен MATLAB версии 2016b или новее, то можно использовать [`piecewise`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/piecewise.html). Если нет, то так:

```
syms y(x)
y(x) = heaviside(x)*heaviside(1/2-x)*x+heaviside(x-1/2)*heaviside(1-x)*(1-x)
```